# Yosemite: replace desktop with Launchpad

Tags: desktop, macos, launchpad

Is there any way to replace the desktop with launchpad?

I would like to do this thing at this point

Kind of gives me the feeling of coming full circle, but ultimately my desktop is just an additional folder full of junk! or completely pristine and free. But I'm never looking at the desktop, ever. So I don't need it.

Comment: This is not a viable concept, really.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no way to switch Desktop and Launchpad like it's in iOS.

But you can at least remove all icons from the desktop. This way it looks clean and you can focus on the Launchpad.

To remove the icons, run this command in the Terminal.app (paste it then run it by hitting Enter):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false; killall Finder
```

For more information, check out the source: http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/23/hide-all-desktop-icons-in-mac-os-x/